# requestAnimationFrame is not defined in web-worker in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-worker, requestanimationframe

I can't find any information why Firefox v91.10.0esr on Windows 10 complains that `requestAnimationFrame` is not defined:

```js
const worker = new Worker(
               URL.createObjectURL(
               new Blob(
                  ["requestAnimationFrame(() => this.postMessage('requestAnimationFrame in web-worker process'))"]
                  , { type: "text/javascript" })));

worker.addEventListener("message", e =>
{
  console.log(e.data);
});


requestAnimationFrame(() => console.log("requestAnimationFrame in main process"));
```

```
19:09:53.100 ReferenceError: requestAnimationFrame is not defined 569ddce0-b6c3-47c9-88b4-89d59445b335:1:1
    <anonymous> blob:null/569ddce0-b6c3-47c9-88b4-89d59445b335:1
```

It works fine on Android Firefox and other browsers (Edge, Chrome).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you expect a dom function be in a worker?

Comment: @Christopher thanks, seems like it's added in v97

Comment: Sorry, i deleted my comment because the issue on bugzilla was closed. But it was just closed recently.  To avoid confusion: There **was** [an issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1738971#c17) and as @vanowm mentioned, it was added in v97.

Comment: @Christopher, do you mind post it as answer, so it can be marked as solved?

Comment: @DanielA.White um...`requestAnimationFrame` has nothing to do with DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox added support for requestAnimationFrame and cancelAnimationFrame in workers with v97 as you can see on this [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1738971). [Comment 17 and 18](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1738971#c17) just confirm it.